# jhipster perform a envers query from a service by reusing the database session

Tags: spring, jhipster, hibernate-envers

I would like to create a service which will perform a auditquery with envers.

After trying to find informations I used this code:

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class SecurityAuditService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityAuditService.class);

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public String findAll() {
        List query = AuditReaderFactory.get( entityManager )
                .createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(MyClass.class, false, true)
                .setFirstResult(4)
                .setMaxResults(2)
                .getResultList();
```

But I have a java null exception with entityManager when trying it. How I could use the existing database session to perform my query?

Thanks,

Alain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entityManager` field is not not injected by Spring, add it to `SecurityAuditService`'s constructor or annotate it with `@Autowired`